# Why can't we swap the order of definite integrals and derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

According to my textbook, the solutions to these two problems are different, but I don't understand why they are different. Can anyone explain? If the integral of a derivative gets you the function back, doesn't the derivative of an integral also get you the function back?

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx} (e^{\arctan x}) dx
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^1 (e^{\arctan x}) dx
$$

Also, while I'm here...why does FTC have a t in it?

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x (e^{\arctan t}) dt
$$

why isn't it just x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\int_0^1e^{\arctan x}\,\mathrm dx$ is a constant, $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_0^1e^{\arctan x}\,\mathrm dx=0$.

On the other hand, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus$$\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}e^{\arctan x}\,\mathrm dx=e^{\arctan 1}-e^{\arctan0}=e^{\pi/4}-1,$$

Comment: OHHH!!! THANK YOU!!!